# GeoJSON parse coordinates and set values to custom structure

Tags: c++, gis, geojson, cpprest-sdk

I need to set GeoJSON coordinates to this structure:

```
struct coord {
   double lat,
   double lon 
};
```

My sample JSON:

```
{
 "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            75.9814453125,
            10.919617760254697
          ],
          [
            76.2451171875,
            11.30770770776545
          ],
          [
            76.728515625,
            11.350796722383672
          ],
          [
            76.904296875,
            10.919617760254697
          ]
        ]
 }
}
```

The code snippet:

```
auto array =  value.as_object()["coordinates"].as_array();
for(auto v = array.begin() ; v < array.end() ; v++ ){
    auto a = (*v).as_array();
    coords.push_back(createCoord(a));
}

amp::AmpFeature::coordinate createCoord(web::json::array coordsJson) {
  coord c;
  if(a.size() == XY){
      c.lon = a.at(0).as_double();
      c.lat = a.at(1).as_double();
  } 
}
```

In the above code I need some other way to set the structure values. This is done using cpprest-sdk json parser. We are fetching the data from sqlite db.

We are dealing with tens of thousands of such lineString geometries. Is there more efficient and faster way to set these values?

Environment : 
OS : Ubuntu 18.04 
C++ version : 17

Comment: Could you specify what is the problem with the current code? Does it not work? Is it too slow? It also seems that your code misses the definition of `createCoord()`? Maybe the last 5 lines are that function?

Comment: Have you considered using the OGR library (https://gdal.org/api/index.html)

Comment: @DanielJunglas There is no problem with the current code. We are dealing with 10000 and more number of records. So searching for other JSON parsers which is more efficient and faster that the existing code. Yes those last five lines are the definition of `createCoord()`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code first reads the *whole* file into a JSON structure and then you go through this structure. It might be worth a try to use an event based parser. With that you don't have the whole JSON value in memory. Maybe this is faster. I have never used such a parser but they do exist.

Comment: We are fetching the data from sqlite db.